# For statement does not repeated strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I what the user input to be repeated 10 times but I get an error.

```
no = input(' any thing typed there will x10')

for i in range(10):
   print(no)
```

But if I change the code to int or something else it works .

```
no = int (input(' any thing typed there will x10'))

for i in range(10):
   print(no)
```

I am probably missing something basic ,but thanks in advance.

I used an app called QPython on my android which might be the problem

Comment: Edit your question and provide the error Python shows when you run the code.

Comment: Both both code versions behave the same if the user enter only numbers, but the second code block will fail if the user enters input other than numbers (i.e. strings or characters, etc), that's a misleading prompt "any thing typed there will x10"

Comment: Are you sure you're using python 3?

Comment: Your code works for me: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#DcoxCoAwDAXQvaf4m@2mq@BhCsYaCEkJEfX01e0Nb6hhA2u/Ik@o@iJO1oZ4O@2/yQk3i@BZ5qmkdJiD/w@v2igvc1kTgO6skdXKGCeJGG5z2T8 "Python 3 – TIO Nexus")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have written is valid **Python 3**, but not valid **Python 2**.  I suspect you are running Python 2, given the question.  Python changed how the input function works between Python 3 and Python 2.  But given your issue, this will fix the issue for Python 2 users (you):

```
no = raw_input(' any thing typed there will x10')

for i in range(10):
   print(no)
```

Comment: I actually coded this on my android so that might be the problem.